# Sfmc - dynamic content dependent on data extension membership

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm in salesforce marketing cloud. I want to show some content depending on if a subscriber exists in a separate data extension. If they are in one data extension, I want to show content A, if they are in another data extension, I want to show content B, etc.  Is there a way to do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: are these 2 DEs being used in the send, or are they separate from the sendable DE you are using on the send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would perform a SQL Activity performing a LEFT JOIN from your original subscriber Data Extension to the two different Data Extension.  Output a Boolean in new fields on whether subscribers are in the joined Data extensions using CASE statements.

Example:

```
SELECT a.subscriberkey
    ,CASE 
        WHEN b.subscriberkey IS NULL
            THEN false
        ELSE true
        END AS FoundinDE1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN c.subscriberkey IS NULL
            THEN false
        ELSE true
        END AS FoundinDE2
FROM subscriberDE AS a
LEFT JOIN DE1 AS b ON a.subscriberkey = b.subscriberkey
LEFT JOIN DE2 AS c ON a.subscriberkey = c.subscriberkey
```

Now that you have the boolean fields, you can use Dynamic Content in the Email to check on the true/false conditions you require.

```
IF FoundinDE1 = True
Display Content A
IF FoundinDE2 = True
Display Content B
```